# POSIX threads / Sockets for my portable program

Tags: posix

I am intending to write a portable program in C/C++ for windows, mac and Unix.
The program will mainly be based on sockets and threads. 
I am considering POSIX threads and sockets for my program initially to be written for Linux,

My questions is would I be able to port my program from linux to to Mac and Windows 7/vista later on without much trouble ?

Thanks,

Comment: For MacOS it should be no problem at all. There are a few advanced POSIX threads features (like robust mutexes) that are available under Linux but not MacOS, but you most likely aren't using anything like that. I can't speak for MS Windows.

Comment: thanks for that thumbs up for u